# Primefaces tabView executes form validation on tab change

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, onchange, tabview

I am having a serious issue with the `p:tabView` component. I have set `dynamic="true"` and `cache="false"` to the tabView. One of the tabs has some input components which are set `required="true"`.

Now when I am changing the tab each time, the form validation is occurring and the FacesMessages are being displayed in growl.

Here is the tab:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
   template="/WEB-INF/templates/globalTemplate.xhtml">

   <ui:define name="title">#{adbBundle['home']}</ui:define>
   <ui:define name="content">
      <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />

      <p:tabView id="adminTabView" dynamic="true" cache="false">
         <p:tab title="#{adbBundle['admin.customerTab.title']}"
            id="customerTab">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/adminCustomer.xhtml" />
         </p:tab>
         <p:tab title="#{adbBundle['admin.activityTab.title']}"
            id="activityTab">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/addActivity.xhtml" />
         </p:tab>
      </p:tabView>

   </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

The adminCustomer.xhtml contains the form and which is:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

   <h:form id="customerForm">
      <p:panel id="addCustomerPanel" toggleable="true"
         header="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.header.new']}">
         <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="addCustomerTable"
            styleClass="addCustomerTable">
            <f:facet name="header">
               <p:outputLabel id="header"
                  value="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.header']}" />
            </f:facet>

            <p:outputLabel for="customerName"
               value="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.customerName']}" />
            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
               <p:inputText id="customerName" styleClass="customerName"
                  autocomplete="off"
                  label="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.customerName']}"
                  value="#{adminController.customerDTO.customerName}"
                  required="true" />               
            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:outputLabel for="customerId"
               value="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.customerId']}" />
            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
               <p:inputText id="customerId" autocomplete="off"
                  label="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.customerId']}"
                  value="#{adminController.customerDTO.customerId}" required="true">
                  <f:validator validatorId="customerIDValidator" />
               </p:inputText>               
            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:outputLabel for="activeStatus"
               value="#{adbBundle['admin.addCustomerPanel.addCustomerTable.activeStatus']}" />
            <h:panelGroup layout="block">
               <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="activeStatus"
                  value="#{adminController.customerDTO.active}" />
            </h:panelGroup>

            <f:facet name="footer">
               <p:commandButton value="#{adbBundle['saveButton']}"
                  actionListener="#{adminController.saveCustomer}"
                  icon="ui-icon-check"
                  update=":growl, @form" />
            </f:facet>
         </p:panelGrid>
      </p:panel>
   </h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

I am unable to find what I am doing wrong and how to resolve it.
I am using Primefaces 3.4.2 with JSF Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg. Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

I have asked this question in PrimeFaces forum too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how `tabView` works. Here are the relevant issues from the PrimeFaces tracker:

- http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3423.
- http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4143

As you can see the first one is marked as WontFix. *The second is a duplicate but at the end you will see another workaround*.

If you read that thread carefully you may notice that some workarounds still exists. Try one of them if you are forced to use `tabView`. Also consider using [PrimeFaces - Wizard](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/wizard.jsf) if you want to use inputs in different tabs.

Comment: I somehow have the feeling you misunderstood the question, but I am not sure. Yes it is the documented behavior, that `tabView` will validate inputs (as according to JSF-Spec), but at least since PF 4.0 there is `immediate="true"` to skip that validation phase. Additionally see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, there is actually a quite simple workaround to prevent the duplicate showing of messages.

Change your growl to the following:

```
<p:growl id="growl" globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" />
```

In case you want to add messages from backing bean side you can do that with the following code:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
   .addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "title", "details");
```

And if you want to be completely safe, you can even specify a for-attribute to the growl, and take that as the first parameter to `addMessage`.