# Primefaces tabview menu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Im having a problem with Primefaces tabview. It's tabs consists of selectOneMenu elements that look like this:

```
`
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.currentItem.marketType}">
 <f:selectItems value="#{bean.marketTypes}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
`
```

Now, I show this view as a dialog every time i select row from a dataTable (in order to edit selected record). The strange behavior is: the first time I refresh the page, i select the row, and the dialog pops out correctly. In all tabs of a tabview, all selectOneMenu elements shows correct data for selected record. However, when i close dialog and reopen it by selecing row again, only those selectOneMenu elements shows correct data, which where in a selected tab from a tabview before the dialog was closed.
Does any one know how to keep data in all tabs every time I open a dialog without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, there is a bug in Primefaces that is described here:

[Primefaces tabView executes form validation on tab change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010537/primefaces-tabview-executes-form-validation-on-tab-change)